# Multidimensional Array and advanced for loop

Tags: java

Say you have the code below with a loop inside of a loop:

```
int[][] practice = new int[10][10];

for(int x[] : practice){
    for(int y : x){

    }
}
```

First of all, what does the `int x[]` part mean. What does the `[]` do? and I'm sure the second for loop is correct. Because the `y` loops through the current row through the `x[]`. But can someone explain what those brackets mean? And if this loop is incorrect please correct it.

Comment: It is more common to write `for (int[] x : practice)` which means the exact same thing.

Comment: That means its indicating that each elements it an integer array.

Comment: Think of your 2-dimensional array as a 1-dimensional array whose elements are 1-dimensional arrays, and I think this will be more clear.  In other words, `int[][]` is an array of `int[]`, which are each an array of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`int x[]` is equivalent to `int[] x`: it declares a variable named `x`, of type `int[]`, i.e array of `int`.

So, the outer loop iterate over every array of int inside the array of arrays of int `practice`.

Answer (score 1):

`int x[]` - A 1 dimensional array of integers called `x`.

A 2d array is simply an array of arrays, so the foreach loop here is saying: "for every 1 dimiensional integer array contained in `practice`, temporarily store refer to that array as `x` do whatever activity is contained in the braces."

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to array of arrays;

First for loop gets you array(`x`) of arrays(`practice`).

Second for loop gives you element(`y`) in array(`x`) or arrays(`practice`).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes renaming variables can really add to the readability of code hopefully this helps:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arrayOfArrays = new int[10][10];

    for (int[] outerArrayElement: arrayOfArrays) {
            //outerArrayElement is an int[]
        for (int innerArrayElement : outerArrayElement) {
               //innerArrayElement is an int
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are creating the 2-dimensional array "practice" then you are iterating on it to get one dimensional arrays from it , then you are iterating on one dimensional array "x" to get the elements from it.